# SwiftData query using two or more rows from the first table

Tags: swift-data

I have a Customer model and a Certificate model.
Each Customer may have more than one Certificates
How can I filter all Certificates from two or more selected Customers using a query in SwiftData.
Note: Selected Customers are stored in a set

Here are the model definitions:

```
@Model
final class Customer {
  @Attribute(.unique) var vat: String
  var name: String
  @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Certificate.customer) var certifications = [Certificate]()
}

@Model
final class Certificate {
  @Attribute(.unique) var no: String
  var customer: Customer?
}
```

and bellow is the view for the certifications

```
struct CertificationList: View {
let customerNames: [String]?
@State var selectedCertifications: Set<Certification> = Set<Certification>()
@Query() private var certificates: [Certificate]
  
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    List(selection: $selectedCertifications) {
      ForEach(certificates) { certificate in
        NavigationLink(certificate.no, value: certificate)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query does no filter anything

Comment: If you already have the Customer objects in memory then you don't need a query, just get the Certificate objects from the to-many property and merge the results.

Comment: If objects are in memory then you are right. But I think you need a query when you have a property for the name for each customer and you need to retrieve the certificates of the customers “APPLE” and “MICROSOFT” for example

Comment: That is not how I interpreted your question, please edit your question and clarify what you mean and any code that is necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: I was not clear. My mistake. I edited my question.Please ignore any syntax error since I copied code from my original project only the necessary lines just for simplicity